# Загрузка файла в облако

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы, url, облако

Требуется создать небольшую серверную часть на Python. Суть в том, что сначала программа должна загрузить файл из облака(гугл диск, файл по ссылке разрешен для просмотра, загрузки и редактирования) на копьютер пользователя, затем произвести с ним какие-либо манипуляции, и потом уже заменить тот файл, который загружался, на отредактированный.
С первыми 2мя пунктами я разобрался, помогите с последним.
Вот код, как я загружаю файл:

```
import urllib.request
logo = urllib.request.urlopen("https://drive.google.com/........download").read()
f = open("qwe4udhcjfhgrty.db", "wb")
f.write(logo)
f.close()
```

Или есть способ редактирования файла от моего имени? То есть мы указываем в своей программе логин и пароль, а она уже за нас входит в аккаунт и что-то там делает?

Comment: Не проще бы использовать https://github.com/gsuitedevs/PyDrive?

Comment: Да, наверное проще... я раньше не знал об этой библиотеке... Спасибо!